# Lightning Carousel is adding empty Indicators to existing images when event is fired

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have two components Stage and Carousel, The stage will have 4 values (stage 1, stage 2, stage 3 and stage 4),  When ever a stage is changed I am pulling Carousel images related to that "stage" from custom object.

This is working for the first time when page is loaded, but when a stage is changed the carousel is adding empty indicators at the end and size is keep increasing whenever the stage is changed again. I have only 2 images, but as shown in below it is showing 4 indicators, If I change the Stage, again it will add 2 more empty indicators.

[image]

**Here is the code:**

Apex Controller:

```
public static List<images__c> getImgs(String stage) {

        return = [select id, Text__c,URL__c,order__c from images__c
           Where Stages__c INCLUDES(: stage)];

        }
```

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="imgs" type="Object[]" />

    <aura:attribute type="String" name="stage" default=""/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:webStageEvent" action="{!c.onStageChange}"/>

        <lightning:carousel disableAutoRefresh="false" disableAutoScroll="false" scrollDuration="8">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.imgs}" var="i">

                       <lightning:carouselImage
                                     src = "{!i.URL__c}"
                                     header = "{!i.Description}" 
                                     alternativeText = "{!i.Text__c}">
            </lightning:carouselImage>
        </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:carousel>
```

Controller.Js

```
onStageChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.stage",event.getParam("stage"));

        helper.getDisplayImg(component,helper);
    }
```

Helper:

```
({
     getDisplayImg : function(component, helper)
    {

        var action = component.get('c.getImgs');
        action.setParams({  
                   stage :component.get("v.stage")
        });

        action.setCallback(this,function(response){

            var stage = response.getStage();

            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.imgs', response.getReturnValue());

            }else if(state === "ERROR"){
                var errors=response.getError();
                if(errors){
                    console.log("Errors",errors);
                    if(errors[0] && errors[0].message)
                    {
                        throw new Error("Error",errors[0].message);
                    }
                }else {
                    throw new Error("Unknown Error");
                }
            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

Comment: this is not reproducible, can you put debug statements in apex and also console.log statements in aura for response and confirm you are getting expected number of images?

Comment: @salesforce-sas thanks for your response, yes I am getting values as 2